# How to scale back target variable using inverse_transform

Tags: python, prediction, inverse-transform

I used StandardScaler() to scale my data before predictions . Now I want to scale back only the predicted values (using inverse_transform) but im unable to do so because it expects to see 4 variables whereas I only want to scale back the target value from my predictions. How can I do this?

```
#Error when i try to transform y_pred and y_test
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (52,) (4,) (52,)
```